# Python/Pandas Subtract Only if Value is not 0

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, subtraction

I'm starting with data that looks something like this, but with a lot more rows:

```
Location  Sample  a     b     c     d     e     f     g     h     i
1         w       14.6  0     0     0     0     0     0     0     16.8
2         x       0     13.6  0     0     0     0     0     0     16.5
3         y       0     0     15.5  0     0     0     0     0     16.9
4         z       0     0     0     0     14.3  0     0     0     15.7
...
```

The data is indexed by the first two columns.  I need to subtract the values in column i from each of the values in a - h, adding a new column to the right of the data frame for each original column.  However, if there is a zero in the first column, I want it to stay zero instead of subtracting.  For example, if my code worked I would have the following columns added to the data frame on the right

```
Location  Sample  ...  a2    b2    c2    d2    e2    f2    g2    h2 
1         w       ...  -2.2  0     0     0     0     0     0     0
2         x       ...  0     -2.9  0     0     0     0     0     0
3         y       ...  0     0     -1.4  0     0     0     0     0
4         z       ...  0     0     0     0     -1.4  0     0     0
...
```

I'm trying to use where in pandas to only subtract the value in column i if the value in the current column is not zero using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

normalizer = i
columns = list(df.columns.values)

for column in columns:
    if column == normalizer: continue
    newcol = gene + "2"
    df[newcol] = df.where(df[column] == 0, 
                df[column] - df[normalizer], axis = 0)
```

I'm using a for loop because the number of columns will not always be the same, and the column that is being subtracted will have a different name using different data sets.

I'm getting this error: "ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 9, placement implies 1".

I think the subtraction is causing the issue, but I can't figure out how to change it to make it work.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**  (pretty fast: roughly 3 times faster than method 2)
1. Select columns that is relavent
2. Do subtraction
3. Elementwise mutiplication with a 0, 1 matrix that constructed before the substraction. Each element in (df_ref > 0) is 0 if it was originally 0 and 1 otherwise.

```
ith_col = df["i"]
subdf = df.iloc[:, 2:-1]  # a - h columns 
df_temp = subdf.sub(ith_col, axis=0).multiply(subdf > 0).add(0)
df_temp.columns = ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2', 'f2', 'g2', 'h2'] # rename columns
df_desired = pd.concat([df, df_temp], axis=1)
```

Note in this method, the 0 is negative. Thus, we have an extra `add(0)` in the end. Yes, a 0 can be negative. :P

**Method 2** (more readable)
1. Find the greater than 0 part with a condition.
2. Select rows that is relavent
3. Substract
4. Fill in 0.

```
ith_col = df["i"]
df[df > 0].iloc[:,2:-1].sub(ith_col, axis=0).fillna(0)
```

The second method is pretty similar to @Wen's answer. Credits to him :P

**Speed comparison of two methods** (tested on Python 3 and pandas 0.20)

```
%timeit subdf.sub(ith_col, axis=0).multiply(subdf > 0).add(0)
688 µs ± 30.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit df[df > 0].iloc[:,2:-1].sub(ith_col, axis=0).fillna(0)
2.97 ms ± 248 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Reference:

[`DataFrame.multiply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.multiply.html) perform elementwise multiplication with another data frame.

Comment: You can use select the columns needed with a list of names. df_ref = df[columnNames]. Then apply the first method. columnNames is a list of string, ['a','b','c','d'] for example.  For missing columns, I am not sure whether you want to keep these missing ones nan or turn them into 0s.

Comment: When I run Method 1, it is giving me the original table without column i.  Nothing has been subtracted.  When I run Method 2, I get the error "ValueError: cannot join with no level specified and no overlapping names".

Comment: @Kimmy the method will not do it in place. It creates a new df. You can try to use methods like `pd.concat` to glue 2 df together.

Comment: I got method 1 to work after some tinkering.  I wasn't able to get method 2 to work.  This is the code I used: `normalizer=i  normalizer_col=df[normalizer]  df_temp=df.copy()  df_temp.drop(normalizer, axis=1, inplace=True)  final_vals=df_temp.sub(normalizer_col, axis=0).multiply(df_temp > 0).add(0)`.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Gald it works :P btw, you can use del df[normalizer] to delete a column. I think for method 2, you can still save the result to a temporary df, like `df_temp`. Then change column names, and concat it with `df`

Answer (score 1):

Using `mask` + `fillna`

```
df.iloc[:,2:-1]=df.iloc[:,2:-1].mask(df.iloc[:,2:-1]==0).sub(df['i'],0).fillna(0)
df
Out[116]: 
   Location Sample    a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h     i
0         1      w -2.2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  16.8
1         2      x  0.0 -2.9  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  16.5
2         3      y  0.0  0.0 -1.4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  16.9
3         4      z  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 -1.4  0.0  0.0  0.0  15.7
```

Update

```
normalizer = ['i','Location','Sample']
df.loc[:,~df.columns.isin(normalizer)]=df.loc[:,~df.columns.isin(normalizer)].mask(df.loc[:,~df.columns.isin(normalizer)]==0).sub(df['i'],0).fillna(0)
```

Comment: How would I do this using the column names instead?  The column I am subtracting often will not be the last one.

Comment: @Kimmy for example if you need 'd', unselect it by `df.loc[:,~df.columns.isin(['d'])]`

Comment: I tried using:    "normalizer = i  ;  ct_vals = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.isin(normalizer)].mask(df.loc[:, ~df.columns.isin(normalizer)]==0).sub(df[normalizer],0).fillna(0)", and got the error "TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]"

Comment: Typing the column name out instead also gives several errors ending in "KeyError: 'i' ".

Comment: @Kimmy you need list like, *only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin()*